# What purpose does [0] serve in numpy.where(y_euler<0.0)[0]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Also what is the difference between this:

```
idx_negative_euler = numpy.where(y_euler<0.0)[0]
```

and this:

```
idx_negative_euler = numpy.where(y_euler<0.0)[0][0]
```

I realize that this returns an array of indices where the array `y_euler` is negative, however I simply can't figure out what the `[0]` or the `[0][0]` at the end of the line is supposed to do.

I couldn't find any documentation regarding this (I'm not even sure what to search for). I've already looked into the `numpy.where` documentation but that didn't help.

Comment: Why not try out the expression without the `[0]`? With it you get the first element from a sequence, so presumably `np.where()[0]` returns a sequence..

Comment: `np.where()` returns a tuple of indices form your array's axis.

Comment: Check out [this tutorial page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator) and search the page for the term `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

`[0]` means "get the first item of the sequence."  For example if you had this list:

```
x = [5, 7, 9]
```

Then `x[0]` would be the first item of that sequence: 5.

`numpy.where()` returns a sequence.  Putting `[0]` on the end of that expression gets the first item in that sequence.

`[0][0]` means "get the first item in the sequence (which is itself also a sequence), and then get the first item in *that* sequence".  So if `numpy.where()` returned a list of lists, `[0][0]` would get the first item in the first list.

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple 1d array:

```
In [60]: x=np.array([0,1,-1,2,-1,0])
```

Where returns a tuple `(...,)` of arrays, one for each dimension:

```
In [61]: np.where(x<0)
Out[61]: (array([2, 4], dtype=int32),)
```

pull the first (here only) element from the tuple

```
In [62]: np.where(x<0)[0]
Out[62]: array([2, 4], dtype=int32)
```

get the first element of the indexing array

```
In [63]: np.where(x<0)[0][0]
Out[63]: 2
```

the whole tuple returned by `where` can be used to index the array.

```
In [64]: x[np.where(x<0)]
Out[64]: array([-1, -1])
```

`x[2,4]`, `x[([2,4],)]` do the same indexing.

The usefulness of the `tuple` value becomes more obvious when working on a 2d or higher dim array.  In that case `np.where(...)[0]` would give the 'rows' index array.  But the `where(...)[0]` is most common in the 1d case where the tuple layer usually isn't needed.